# Get SQL Server Agent jobs configured with Email Notification

Tags: sql, sql-server-agent

I have lot of jobs in my SQL server agent. I want to know which all the jobs are configured with email notification. I can do individually by editing and checking for the job steps. Any query/procedure to give the job names that have email notification in one shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this query on `[msdb]` db.

```
use [msdb]

select j.name, o.name, o.email_address 
from 
[dbo].[sysjobs] j 
inner join [dbo].[sysoperators] o on j.notify_email_operator_id  = o.id
```

Comment: It works. I am new to all these DBA conecpts. If I want to get the Email Text also with the job how can I get it.

Comment: You can get message text from `[dbo].[sysalerts]` table.

Comment: @sarlan if I wan't to filter jobs belonging to a particular database then

Comment: You can use `[sysjobsteps]`table for getting database info. For example `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysjobs] j INNER JOIN [dbo].[sysjobsteps] s ON j.job_id = s.job_id WHERE s.database_name ='master'`